# Genotypes without Recombination

Tags: genetics

When given that the parent generation's genotypes are linked traits, how do you determine the genotypes of the F1 generation when no recombination has occurred.  For example, given the parents BbNn and bbnn what would be the expected genotypes of the F1 generation to be?

My current understanding is to follow Meiosis and separate the homologous pairs into Bb Nn and bb nn. Then, because no crossover is occurring, my guess would be that the daughter genotypes are BbNn and bbnn.  However, in reality, the answer should be Bbnn and bbNn.  Am I doing something wrong?  How would I draw the related chromosomes?

Answer (score 0):

> My current understanding is to follow Meiosis and separate the
> homologous pairs into Bb Nn and bb nn.

No.  If the alleles are linked, then you either have one chromosome with BN, and the other with bn, or you have one chromosome with Bn, and the other with bN.  From this information alone, you can't know which.  Your answer assumes the first situation is how the alleles are linked, the given answer assumes the second.

Comment: So.  Just to make sure I'm following, the link could either be BN and bn or Bn and bN but it is impossible to know which.  Thus, either answer would be correct?  If not, how you would you know which way the linking is taking place?

Note:  I am studying from the following practice set if you would like to see the original question text:  https://ocw.mit.edu/courses/biology/7-01sc-fundamentals-of-biology-fall-2011/genetics/linkage-and-recombination-genetic-maps/MIT7_01SCF11_3.2sol1.pdf

Comment: It's impossible to know which given only what you posted.  If there's more information, that would change things.

Comment: @hhghh You can often figure out the gametic phase of BbNn parent from genotypes of its parents. Sure enough, this information is included in the link you provided. By omitting it in your question you have rendered your question unanswerable.

Comment: Ah.  Okay.  Could you elaborate more on how you would do that?  I'm not 100% sure I understand.  Sorry.  So the parents of BbNn are BBnn and bbNN.  From this, how would you determine how linking is taking place?